# Convert column to Row for query with joins MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How do I convert the GROUP_CONCAT row result as a separate columns for this query?

```
SELECT Email, Address, CityName, StateName, PostalCode,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      PP.PrefKey
    )
  )
    FROM Profile P 
    LEFT JOIN ProfileAddress PA ON  P.ProfileID = PA.ProfileID
     LEFT JOIN ProfilePrefs PP   ON PP.ProfileID = PA.ProfileID
    WHERE P.ProfileID = 6;
```

[image]

DESIRED OUTPUT OF QUERY RESULT

email | address | cityname | statename | postalcode | availability | certifications | commute ....

**ProfilePrefs  table**
[image]

Comment: Provide desired output. PS. It seems that you want PIVOT - this is not supported by MySQL. Conditional aggregate may help.

Comment: yes I'm looking for a pivot to change it into column names , how to achieve through aggregate?@Akina

Comment: Does there exists complete list of `PrefKey` values somewhere?

Comment: Yes in  ProfilePrefs Table there is a column PrefKey, attached screenshot in question.@Akina

Comment: "this query" is a broken reference, because you deleted what it refers to in you most recent edit. Please undo the edit or otherwise fix the broken reference. Make sure that the question still matches the answers you got. Changing a question so that an existing answer seems invalid is considered a "moving target" question and not appreciated. For now I will simply roll back your edit, for you to do the fine tuning.

Answer (score -1):

you can use aliases.
if i understand your question, your answer is :

```sql
SELECT Email, Address, CityName, StateName, PostalCode,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      PP.PrefKey
    )
  ) AS SAMPLE_COLUMN_NAME
    FROM Profile P 
    LEFT JOIN ProfileAddress PA ON  P.ProfileID = PA.ProfileID
     LEFT JOIN ProfilePrefs PP   ON PP.ProfileID = PA.ProfileID
    WHERE P.ProfileID = 6;
```

and you can use SAMPLE_COLUMN_NAME in your query.
you can read more [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/)

Comment: I Don't want to rename the column I want them to be changed to columns, please check output

Answer (score -1):

Pivotting via conditional aggregation looks like

```sql
SELECT Email, Address, CityName, StateName, PostalCode,
       MAX(PP.PrefKey = 'availability') availability,
       MAX(PP.PrefKey = 'certifications') certifications,
       ...
FROM Profile P 
LEFT JOIN ProfileAddress PA ON  P.ProfileID = PA.ProfileID
LEFT JOIN ProfilePrefs PP   ON PP.ProfileID = PA.ProfileID
WHERE P.ProfileID = 6 /* may select a list of IDs or remove for to get all IDs */
GROUP BY Email, Address, CityName, StateName, PostalCode;
```

Of course the complete list of `PP.PrefKey` values must exist for hardcoding.

If such list is dynamic then only stored procedure with dynamic SQL may solve.

Comment: Cant it be dynamic ?

Comment: @art In single query form - no.

Comment: and under the column PrefKey can we get PrefValue rather than 1 ? @Akina

Comment: like under Availability I get 2, under  certifications i get []

Comment: @art Replace simple condition with according CASE and assign any value you need in. Maybe even replace MAX() with, for example, GROUP_CONCAT(CASE).

Comment: could you please tell how  , becuase for me it is returning complete aggregated result under one column

Comment: Create some sample fiddle ( for example, at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 ), add the link into the question, show desired output for this fiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224775/discussion-between-art-and-akina).